# Sind/Ist bei Aufzählung

Tags: grammar, verb, grammatical-number, list

Ich habe folgenden Satz und bin mir nicht recht sicher, ob nun *ist* oder *sind* hier besser angebracht ist.

> Wir wollen euch mitteilen, dass das rote und blaue Programm in letzter Zeit gewachsen **ist/sind**.

Diese Frage ist zwar ähnlich wie bereits andere gestellte Fragen hier, jedoch sind die Ergebnisse nicht 1:1 übertragbar auf meine Frage. Daher sehe ich diese nicht als Duplikat an.

Comment: sind... irgendwo sollte hier eine dublette rumliegen

Comment: @Vogel612: Schau mal nach rechts. Ich würde ja selbst zur Tat schreiten, aber ich möchte hier keine alleinige Entscheidung fällen.

Comment: @Vogel612 related yes, but the result is difficult to transfer to this question imo.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Sehe ich auch so. Plädiere für Wiederöffnen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ist" impliziert, dass das Programm tatsächlich rot *und* blau ist, was eher unwahrscheinlich ist.

Normalerweise sollte man zumindest sagen

> ...dass das rote und das blaue Programm gewachsen sind.

Comment: vielleicht klarer zu Verstehen: *" [...], dass die Programme Rot und Blau in letzter Zeit gewachsen sind."*

Comment: Danke hierfür :) Dann war mein erster Gedanke gar nicht mal falsch.

Answer (score 0):

Normalerweise würde man in diesem Zusammenhang "sind" verwenden. Trotzdem klingt es meiner Meinung nach nicht besonders gut. Ich würde "sowohl..als auch" verwenden und den Satz wie folgt konstruieren:

> Wir wollen euch mitteilen, dass sowohl das rote als auch das blaue Programm in letzter Zeit gewachsen ist.

Dadurch wird auch deutlich, dass es sich um zwei unterschiedliche Programme handelt.

Comment: Nette Alternative. Danke :)