# Schreibt man "ist" oder "sind" bei Aufzählungen

Tags: word-choice

Schreibt man den Satz mit "ist" oder mit "sind"?

> Ruhm und Ehre oder Geld, sind/ist nicht alles auf der Welt.

Comment: Vielleicht hilft dir auch das [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25483/sind-ist-bei-aufz%c3%a4hlung?noredirect=1&lq=1). Der Fragende hatte keine Übertragbarkeit der Antworten  mit denen aus dem Link von @mtwde gesehen.

Comment: "Sind" ist hier allerdings m.W. nur deshalb richtig, weil es ein einschließendes Oder ist (es sind auch Ruhm und Ehre UND Geld mit umfasst). Über "oder" steht in der anderen Antwort gar nichts, ich finde deshalb nicht, dass die diese Frage vollständig bantwortet.

Comment: Man kann die Aufzählung der 3 als eine Kategorie begreifen "(Ruhm und Ehre oder Geld) ist nicht alles auf der Welt" - oder als 2 Kategorien "(Ruhm und Ehre) oder (Geld) sind nicht alles auf der Welt, sowie - nur ist das recht mechanisch, mathematisch gedacht - "Ruhm und (Ehre oder Geld)" aber semantisch ausgeschlossen. Wg. Punkt 1, der die Aufzählung von Ruhm, Ehre und Geld als eine Einheit betrachtet, ist jedoch bei der Frage https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/singular-plural-bei-aufz%c3%a4hlungen mit "Ziel und Zweck" ganz ähnlich gelagert.